# Is this a solid workout plan for a beginner working out at home?

Tags: weight-loss, bodybuilding

AI generated this fitness plan for me a ppl workout. Is this a good, solid workout?

Six-Day Push-Pull-Legs (PPL) Workout Schedule with Cardio (No Equipment)
Day 1: Push + Cardio

Push Exercises:
Push-Ups: 4 sets x 15-20 reps
Tricep Dips: 3 sets x 15-20 reps
Pike Push-Ups (for shoulders): 3 sets x 15-20 reps

Push Cardio:
Treadmill Cardio: 30 minutes of brisk walking or jogging (adjust speed as per your fitness level)

Day 2: Pull + Cardio

Pull Exercises:
Bodyweight Rows (using a sturdy table or low bar): 4 sets x 15-20 reps
Reverse Snow Angels (for upper back): 3 sets x 15-20 reps
Bicep Curls (using household items as resistance): 3 sets x 15-20 reps

Pull Cardio:
Treadmill Cardio: 30 minutes of brisk walking or jogging (vary incline and speed for intensity)
Day 3: Legs + Cardio

Leg Exercises:
Bodyweight Squats: 4 sets x 20-25 reps
Lunges (alternating legs): 3 sets x 15-20 reps per leg
Calf Raises: 3 sets x 20-25 reps

Leg Cardio:
Treadmill Cardio: 30 minutes of brisk walking or jogging (experiment with intervals for variety)
Day 4: Rest or Light Activity

Day 5: Push + Cardio

Push Exercises:
Wide Grip Push-Ups: 4 sets x 15-20 reps
Tricep Dips (using a stable chair or bench): 3 sets x 15-20 reps
Pike Push-Ups: 3 sets x 15-20 reps

Push Cardio:
Treadmill Cardio: 30 minutes of brisk walking or jogging (adjust speed based on comfort)
Day 6: Pull + Cardio

Pull Exercises:
Bodyweight Rows: 4 sets x 15-20 reps
Reverse Snow Angels: 3 sets x 15-20 reps
Bicep Curls (using household items): 3 sets x 15-20 reps

Pull Cardio:
Treadmill Cardio: 30 minutes of brisk walking or jogging (vary incline and speed for intensity)
Day 7: Rest or Light Activity

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to invest in a pull-up bar, maybe some dumbells. In general, push-pull-legs is a generic muscle-building exercise split where you do these for 3 days, repeat, and then take your one rest day for the week. Push = chest, tricep, and shoulders. Pull = Back, bicep. Legs = Quad, Hamstring, and Calf. If you could look up about two exercises per muscle and do 3-4 sets of each exercise you will find great progress in this and your consistency. Goodluck...